# How to remove or exclude a schema that WCF adds that isn't used?

Tags: wcf, wsdl

I've created a webservice in Visual studio with WCF and when looking at the generated WSDL it includes a reference to http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization which contains a lot of type specifications. I do not use any of these specifications. Does anyone know why WCF adds this and if there's any way to get rid of it?

The xml added to my wsdl looks like this when using the singleWsdl argument on my service:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="anyType" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType" />
  <xs:element name="anyURI" nillable="true" type="xs:anyURI" />
  <xs:element name="base64Binary" nillable="true" type="xs:base64Binary" />
  <xs:element name="boolean" nillable="true" type="xs:boolean" />
  <xs:element name="byte" nillable="true" type="xs:byte" />
  <xs:element name="dateTime" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime" />
  <xs:element name="decimal" nillable="true" type="xs:decimal" />
  <xs:element name="double" nillable="true" type="xs:double" />
  <xs:element name="float" nillable="true" type="xs:float" />
  <xs:element name="int" nillable="true" type="xs:int" />
  <xs:element name="long" nillable="true" type="xs:long" />
  <xs:element name="QName" nillable="true" type="xs:QName" />
  <xs:element name="short" nillable="true" type="xs:short" />
  <xs:element name="string" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="unsignedByte" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
  <xs:element name="unsignedInt" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
  <xs:element name="unsignedLong" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedLong" />
  <xs:element name="unsignedShort" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedShort" />
  <xs:element name="char" nillable="true" type="tns:char" />
  <xs:simpleType name="char">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:int" />
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:element name="duration" nillable="true" type="tns:duration" />
  <xs:simpleType name="duration">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:duration">
      <xs:pattern value="\-?P(\d*D)?(T(\d*H)?(\d*M)?(\d*(\.\d*)?S)?)?" />
      <xs:minInclusive value="-P10675199DT2H48M5.4775808S" />
      <xs:maxInclusive value="P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:element name="guid" nillable="true" type="tns:guid" />
  <xs:simpleType name="guid">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="[\da-fA-F]{8}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{12}" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:attribute name="FactoryType" type="xs:QName" />
  <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:ID" />
  <xs:attribute name="Ref" type="xs:IDREF" />
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree there is no need to remove it. Also many times it is used and you do not know about it. The way to change default wsdl generatio is by implementing IWsdlExportExtension:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iwsdlexportextension.aspx

Comment: I partly agree that there might be no need to remove it, but why include it at all?
I guessed that IWsdlExportExtension was the way to remove it if no other schema uses it, but was hoping for a nicer solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's too late now, but I ran into this issue and was able to solve it.  The reason I wanted to remove it was because I was generating clients in both Java and RPG, and the `wsdl2java` and `wsdl2rpg` tools generate large, ugly data structures based on that schema.

In my case, it was because I was using the `DataContract` serializer, and some of the objects I was serializing had members of types that didn't have the `[DataContract]` attribute.  To make that extra schema go away, everything being serialized, all the way down the type tree needed to have that attribute.

It also had this problem whenever a there was an inherited public member on the service contracts.

Comment: Always interested in getting my stuff better. :)
Checked my classes and interfaces and as far as I can see all classes have the [DataContract] and all class members have the [DataMember]. It is a very simple contract so there's no inheritance.

Comment: Could it be that I'm using "odd" types like int? and IEnumerable<T> in the contracts?

Comment: Possibly, we didn't have any generic types, so that might be your issue.

Comment: @Markus Most likely as according to the [XmlSerializer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) documentation section: **Serialization of ArrayList and Generic List**

    "The XmlSerializer cannot serialize or deserialize the following:
    
     Arrays of ArrayList 
    
     Arrays of List<T>"

Answer (score 0):

The XSD definition for microsoft's WSDL implementation imports this namespace (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff386135%28v=office.12%29.aspx)).

Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: Since nothing(or at least I can't find anything) in the wsdl uses the types specified by the schema I don't see a point in having it there. Just seems unnecessary to include information that is not used.